# OpenGL ES 2 Grid/Plane in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, grid, opengl-es-2.0

How do I create a grid/plane of verticies. Think a rectangle with more than 4 points (a rectangle made of many connected triangles, not just two) I don't want to specify an array of 50+ verticies, which I could and use triangle_strip. There must be some way to do it procedurally, perhaps subdividing somehow (it only needs to be done once). I need to access the points in a vertex shader.

Comment: How big do you want it to be and how many vertices?

Comment: hmm.. lets go with a 100x100 grid, 1000 verticies and see how fast it can run. Why does it matter though?

Comment: So you want to, say, load in a model of some terrain, and then subdivide one quad in that terrain into a big grid of vertices so you can model the effects of an explosion ripping a big hole in it?

Comment: I suppose, but not that exactly